# Error during sending mail

Tags: python, email, send

I try to send mail via python. I got a function:

```
def mail():
    fromaddr = 'mymail@gmail.com'  
    toaddrs  = 'targetmail@o2.pl'  
    msg = 'There was a terrible error that occured and I wanted you to know!'  


    # Credentials (if needed)  
    username = 'mymail@gmail.com'  
    password = 'password'  

    # The actual mail send  
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')  
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()  
    server.login(username,password)  
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)  
    server.quit()
```

When I try to execute this function it whows me WinError 10060. Error text below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\python-factory\ServiceChecker\main\mainBlock.py", line 75, in <module>  mail()
File "C:\python-factory\ServiceChecker\main\mainBlock.py", line 65, in mail server =   smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')  
File "C:\Python34\Lib\smtplib.py", line 242, in __init__ (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "C:\Python34\Lib\smtplib.py", line 321, in connect self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
File "C:\Python34\Lib\smtplib.py", line 292, in _get_socket self.source_address)
File "C:\Python34\Lib\socket.py", line 509, in create_connection raise err
File "C:\Python34\Lib\socket.py", line 500, in create_connection sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]
```

I don't know where is problem... i tried many mail servers (gmail,o2,wp,) all of them returned the same error. I tried also other available solutions in the internet to send mail via pyython.... the same problem...

Please help

Comment: 1) try to indent your code properly!

Comment: It seems like the line `smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')` is failing. It works for me. Does the machine you are running this on have a good connection to the internet?

Comment: it'sjust pasted wrong in program it's good

Comment: I gotta corporate network... May it be a reason?

Comment: here is my code: https://github.com/zagorulkinde/fakesmtp which do the same

Comment: also, do use any proxy on your machine?

Comment: Do you have another connection you can run the code over?

Comment: Ok code works... I used mail server which is not blocked :D Thanks for all help everybody :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your posted backtrace, you are failing at the line

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
```

I've run that line and it works for me. The clue is in the `TimeoutError`. I believe you are having networking problems and the code itself is fine.

You do have an extra call to `ehlo` but as it stands you are not getting that far.

Additionally, it would probably be better to pass the port number as a separate argument, rather than using a colon to split it. E.g.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587)
```

The documentation for smptlib is here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html

Comment: Reason may be a corporate network... main server may block my script when I try to run it...

Comment: It's probably best to check with your sysadmin, as people on SO with no knowledge of your network topology can only help so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the second server.ehlo() . The one just before login. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`toaddrs` should be a list

```
toaddrs  = ['targetmail@o2.pl']
```